# MySQL I want to select all the multiple ordered customers' order history

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all the multiple ordered customers' order history.

order_details table is like this

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| customer_id | store_id                             |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|           1 | 3g07gd22-7eba-gae9-8aeb-aae3bae6wga0 |
|           1 | 3g07gd22-7eba-gae9-8aeb-aae3bae6wga0 |
|           1 | aq8riuqj-vaef-fae2-aher-28acjxreqjxw |
|           2 | 239jfa2r-a3ga-afoi-saf3-ap093fj40qwf |
|           3 | a1lkjerq-fape-bile-aof-asfdajvaa2938 |
|           3 | 239842as-2cr3-p892-sl94-acc3qpobcqw4 |
```

I wrote as follow,

```
SELECT customer_id,store_id FROM order_details GROUP BY customer_id HAVING COUNT(customer_id) > 1;
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| customer_id | store_id                             |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|           1 | 3g07gd22-7eba-gae9-8aeb-aae3bae6wga0 |
|           3 | a36nn0r4-aq3c-76ea-baa4-73gba43q7aa1 |
```

I need the result like

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| customer_id | store_id                             |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|           1 | 3g07gd22-7eba-gae9-8aeb-aae3bae6wga0 |
|           1 | 3g07gd22-7eba-gae9-8aeb-aae3bae6wga0 |
|           1 | aq8riuqj-vaef-fae2-aher-28acjxreqjxw |
|           3 | a1lkjerq-fape-bile-aof-asfdajvaa2938 |
|           3 | 239842as-2cr3-p892-sl94-acc3qpobcqw4 |
```

I want to how to write the sql code.
I wish you could this ploblem.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that, from our point of view (the poor souls who you have asked for assistance), a string like '2cr3' is no less intelligible than '239842as-2cr3-p892-sl94-acc3qpobcqw4'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT customer_id, store_id
FROM (SELECT od.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as cnt
      FROM order_details
     ) od
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the original table with the subquery that gets the multiordered customers.

```
SELECT od.*
FROM order_details AS od
JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM order_details 
    GROUP BY customer_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS od1 ON od.customer_id = od1.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join a derived table that aggregates and filters the customers with more than one appearance.

```
SELECT od1.*
       FROM order_details od1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT od2.customer_id
                               FROM order_details od2
                               GROUP BY od2.customer_id
                               HAVING count(*) > 1) x
                       ON x.customer_id = od1.customer_id;
```

If the table has a (primary) key, you can also use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT od1.*
       FROM order_details od1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM order_detail od2
                            WHERE od2.customer_id = od1.customer_id
                                  AND (od2.<1st key column>,
                                       ...
                                       od2.<nth key column>) <> (od1.<1st key column>,
                                                                 ...
                                                                 od1.<nth key column>));
```